# Application of superposition theorem in solving the voltages of the diodes

Tags: diodes

Why do we need to apply superposition in this problem to determine the V0 instead of assuming that only Si diode will turn "on"  since it has a lower knee voltage compared to the GaAs diode?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fegtQa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Both diodes are on.

Comment: KCL always works. The solution for a diode with a series resistance (which must include both the internal bulk value as well as your external resistors at the diode cathodes in your schematic) is:$$I_{_\text{D}}\left(V_{_\text{D}},R_i,I_{_{\text{SAT}_T}},\eta,V_T,R_{_\text{S}}\right) =\frac{\eta\,V_T}{R_i+R_{_\text{S}}}\cdot \operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac{I_{_{\text{SAT}_T}}\cdot\left(R_i+R_{_\text{S}}\right)}{\eta\:V_T}\cdot e^{^{\left[\frac{V_{_\text{D}}-I_{_{\text{SAT}_T}}\left(R_i+R_{_\text{S}}\right)}{\eta\:V_T}\right]}}\right)-I_{_{\text{SAT}_T}}$$

Comment: If the resistor ahead of each diode is \$R_i\$ and you specify \$I_{_{\text{D}_\text{SI}}}\left(V_{_\text{D}},R_i\right)\$ for the silicon diode using its parameters and temperature and series resistance, \$R_{_\text{S}}\$, and similarly \$I_{_{\text{D}_\text{GaAs}}}\left(V_{_\text{D}},R_i\right)\$ for the GaAs diode, then for the shared node:$$V_x=R_3\cdot\left(I_{_{\text{D}_\text{SI}}}\left(V_1-V_x,R_1\right)+I_{_{\text{D}_\text{GaAs}}}\left(V_1-V_x,R_2\right)\right)$$Applied, iteratively. (Superposition requires homogeneity and additivity, which diodes don't exhibit.)

Comment: If you want to see the Lambert W-function applied in written papers, a good example can be found in *"Exact Analytical Solution of the Diode Ideality Factor of a pn Junction Device Using Lambert W-function Model"* by Habibe Bayhan & A. Sertap Kavasoglu.

Answer (score 3):

Superposition is only valid for linear systems, and diodes are not linear, so the applicability  here is dubious.

P.S. I say “dubious” here rather than ruling out applicability entirely because it would be possible to use superposition to deal with small-signal (like millivolts) variations about a bias point using linearized diode models. But nothing in the problem suggests that is the goal here.

Answer (score 2):

As Spehro's answer says, superposition is not applicable here because superposition applies to linear systems, and diodes are nonlinear devices.

Simple diode circuits are generally solved by a simple guess and check method.
Guess which diodes are on. Solve the circuit with that assumption. Check whether the diodes you guessed were on are indeed passing a forward current, and whether the diodes you guessed were off do indeed have a reverse bias voltage. If you find a diode that isn't biased correctly, then your guess was wrong and you make a different guess and solve again.

As you gain experience you will have a better chance of making a right guess. For example in this circuit you would not guess that both diodes are off.

> ... instead of assuming that only Si diode will turn "on" since it has a lower knee voltage compared to the GaAs diode?

You can make either assumption ... Only the silicon diode is on, or both diodes are on. Then proceed with the solution. If you find that your assumptions lead to an incorrect result, try the other assumption and solve again.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are both diodes "on," but it's easy to see that that's so. If you assume that one of them is "off," Then Vo is (10V-Vf)/2 - somewhere just under 5V. Then look at the other diode: its anode would be at 10V and its cathode near 5V. It's not off.

The problem is something you'll never encounter IRL, so there's some way it relates to what you're studying right now. We weren't sitting in that class, but it's a safe bet that the question wasn't about semiconductor physics, as @Spehro pointed out. Probably you're expected to use some ballpark Vf for each diode, and then solve using superposition.

Incidentally, Vf for the GaAs diode isn't all that different from a typical Vf for a Si diode.